# c-cant printf the cost

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
 float L=0; //L is litre
 float gallon;
 gallon = 3.785*L;
 char input;
 float cost;

 printf("Hello, welcome to PetrolUpHere!!\n");
 printf("Would u like unleaded or diesel fuel?");
 scanf("%c", &input);
 printf("Enter the litre you want to fuel:");
 scanf("%f", &L);

 switch (input) {
 case 'u' :
 cost = 1.98*gallon;
 printf("The cost is :%f ",&cost);
 break;

 case 'd' :
 cost = 1.29*gallon;
 printf("The cost is :%f ",&cost);
 break;
 }

 getch();
 return 0;
 }
```

The program cant show the cost outcome and only show cost = 0.0000 after i finish input the scanf statement and also L value. I,m new for c program and hope can get help. Thank

Comment: Adding a newline should solve it. Otherwise the output buffer is not flushed. You can also call `fflush` manually.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use binary floating-point types such as `float` to compute monetary amounts. The rounding of monetary computations is defined according to precise rules referring to the decimal representation.

Answer (score 1):

you have already done multiply the L to calculate gallon

```
float L=0; //L is litre
 float gallon;
 gallon = 3.785*L;  //here gallon is zero already
```

so you probebaly getting the

```
printf("The cost is :%f ",&cost);
```

out put `he cost is :address`

so try

```
 gallon = 3.785*L; // try this here 
 switch (input) {
```

and

```
printf("The cost is :%f ", cost);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem, gallon is 0:

```
 float L=0; //L is litre
 gallon = 3.785*L;
```

you should multiple after your read the litres:

```
float L=0; //L is litre
float gallon=3.785f;
...
//read liters
scanf("%f", &L);
...
cost = 1.98f*gallon*L;
```

Answer (score 1):

With this line of code:

```
float my_var;
printf("Hi %f", &my_var);
```

you will print the address to my_var, ie: where it is stored in the memory. Not the value of the variable. I think you got this confused because your scanf needs a pointer to where the value you want to update is stored. Do some reading on pointers and it will be a bit clearer. The fix for now is to change your `printf` statements to something like:

```
float my_var;
printf("Hi %f", my_var);
```

Also, your gallon line needs to be moved after all the input from the user, otherwise you will just multiply it by 0 at the start of the program and it will stay being zero instead of the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 changes

```
 gallon = 3.785*L;
```

needs to be moved below all the `scanfs`

2nd change is to print `cost` and not `&cost`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the statement "gallon = 3.785*L;" after reading the L from user other wise gallon will become Zero as L is initialized to Zero.Hence the value of cost also becomes Zero.

And also remove the '&' from printf statement.
It will definitely work this time.